# Hadoop nodes do not ask for passwords during start

Tags: hadoop, ssh, namenode

When I try to ssh into localhost, I am prompted for password. See below
"
ssh connection to localhost:

```
[hadoop@mftrhel74 sbin]$ ssh localhost
hadoop@localhost's password:
Last login: Fri Aug 23 15:44:08 2019 from mah"
```

---The above statement means, passwordless connection is not setup----

But when I try to start Hadoop nodes as below, it doesn't prompt for password.

And the nodes are not starting, I see below message

I think it should prompt me to enter the password for the user just like as SSH connection is to be established.

```
[hadoop@mftrhel74 ~]$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [mftrhel74]
mftrhel74: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
Starting datanodes
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [mftrhel74]
mftrhel74: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

************I DO NOT WANT A PASSWORDLESS CONNECTION*****

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this start-dfs.sh script, or at least the relevant parts of it.

Comment: Edited the question so it makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you are able to log in to one of the nodes with SSH, however probably you have not set up passwordless ssh between the nodes, so the steps you try to execute from the node will fail.

Here is some documentation that should explain that you need to set up passwordless ssh or otherwise install an ambari client (assuming you work on HDP).

https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.2/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-chap1-5-2.html